# The regular expression in angular source code

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

just read the code below in angular source code. It's part of dependency injection. Basically this is more about regular expression.

```
var FN_ARGS = /^function\s*[^\(]*\(\s*([^\)]*)\)/m;
var FN_ARG_SPLIT = /,/;
var FN_ARG = /^\s*(_?)(\S+?)\1\s*$/;
var STRIP_COMMENTS = /((\/\/.*$)|(\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/))/mg;
var $injectorMinErr = minErr('$injector');
function annotate(fn) {
  var $inject,
      fnText,
      argDecl,
      last;

  if (typeof fn === 'function') {
    if (!($inject = fn.$inject)) {
      $inject = [];
      if (fn.length) {
        fnText = fn.toString().replace(STRIP_COMMENTS, '');
        argDecl = fnText.match(FN_ARGS);
        forEach(argDecl[1].split(FN_ARG_SPLIT), function(arg){
          arg.replace(FN_ARG, function(all, underscore, name){
            $inject.push(name);
          });
        });
      }
      fn.$inject = $inject;
    }
  } else if (isArray(fn)) {
    last = fn.length - 1;
    assertArgFn(fn[last], 'fn');
    $inject = fn.slice(0, last);
  } else {
    assertArgFn(fn, 'fn', true);
  }
  return $inject;
}
```

I try to run the code below in my chrome console, what confused me is **where is the second element coming from?**

As for my understanding, I think it should just return the first element which is `function testService(testService, loginService)`.

```
var FN_ARGS = /^function\s*[^\(]*\(\s*([^\)]*)\)/m;
var testFunc = function testService (testService, loginService) {
    loginService.login();
}
var str = testFunc.toString();
var arr = str.match(FN_ARGS);
console.log(arr);
//["function testService(testService, loginService)", "testService, loginService"]
```

Could anybody help me about this, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match` returns the entire string if it matches at index 0. The other indices represent regular expression groups that have matched. You can declare a group within a regex with parenthesis. In this case, the group is `([^\)]*)`.

Comment: Thx for you help, just check the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references) document here.  : )